# False alarm: Chrome believes number field is credit card field

Tags: google-chrome, credit-card, autofill, html-input

I have a form with **no credit card fields at all**. Still, on one of the number fields, Chrome says *Credit card autofill is disabled because this form does not use a secure connection*:

```
<input type="number" value="0" name="category[priority]" id="category_priority">
```

The app will use HTTPS in production, but this is a false alarm anyway.

How can I tell Chrome that field is not a credit card field? Things I tried:

- `step="1"`
- `autocomplete="off"`
- `x-autocompletetype="other"`

Comment: There is no credit card input. It's just a number field.

Comment: Can you share the full html?  That fragment should not trigger the autofill mechanism and does not for me if run in isolation.